# Map Entry conversion with Map Tree

Tags: java, dictionary, treemap

So what I have been trying to do is use a TreeMap I previously had and apply it to this method in which I convert it into a set and have it go through a Map Entry Loop. What I wish to do is invert my previous TreeMap into the opposite (flipped) TreeMap

'When I run my code, it gives me a comparable error. Does this mean I have to implement the comparable method? I convereted the arrayList into an Integer so I thought the comparable method would support it. Or is it just something wrong with my code

Error: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.ArrayList cannot be cast to java.lang.Comparable

Overview: Originally, my intended purpose for the program was to make a Treemap that read from a text document and specifically found all the words and the index/rows of where the words were located. Now I wish to make a "top ten" list that contains the most used words. I wanted to "flip" my treemap so that the integer values would be what would be put in order and the string would follow

```
public static void getTopTenWords(TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map) {
    Set<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>>> set = map.entrySet();
    TreeMap<Integer, String> temp = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();
    int count = 1;
    for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : set){
        if(temp.containsKey(entry.getValue())) {
            Integer val = entry.getValue().get(count);
            val++;
            temp.put(val, entry.getKey());
        }
        else {
            temp.put(entry.getValue().get(count), entry.getKey());
        }
        count++;
     }

}
```

Comment: Your key is of `String` type, your value is of `ArrayList` type. And you are doing `temp.containsKey(entry.getValue())` which will always be `false`. Your temp map declaration says the key should be of `Integer` type. Your code is quite messed up. Your statement isn't clear enough to explain what exactly you are trying to achieve. Elaborate with some example.

Comment: I can't really get the purpose of your method. You want to flip your `TreeMap`, its fine. I can't stop you from doing this. But for what purpose? What does your original `TreeMap` contain, and what you want to achieve from the new `TreeMap`. Please explain clearly with an example if possible.

Comment: My apologies, it left out a piece of my question when I submitted it. I edited it now though

Comment: @James.. Were you trying to create an `TreeMap<List<Integer>, String>`? If yes, then mind you, you can't have mutable objects as key in your `Map`. Secondly, the keys in your `TreeMap` should be `Comparable`.  ---  Please tell us what your : - `TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map` contains?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Now I wish to make a "top ten" list that contains the most used words.
>   I wanted to "flip" my treemap so that the integer values would be what
>   would be put in order and the string would follow

Note that a `Map` contains only unique keys. So, if you try to keep your `count` as key, then you would need to put it in your `Map` by creating a new object with `new Integer(count)`.

If you put your count in `Map` like: - `map.put(2, "someword")`, then there are chances that your previous count value gets overwritten, because `Integer` caches the values in `range: - [-128 to 127]`. So, the integer values between these range will be `interned` if you don't create a new object. And hence two `Integer` with value say `2` will point to same `Integer object`, and hence resulting in duplicate key.

Secondly, in your code: -

```
if (temp.containsKey(entry.getValue()))
```

using the above if statement, you are comparing an `ArrayList` with an `Integer` value. `temp` contains `key` which are `integers`. And values in `entry` are `ArrayList`. So, that will fail at runtime. Also, since your `orginal` Map contains just the location of the `word` found in the `text file`. So, just what you need to do is, get the size of `arraylist` for each word, and make that a key.

You would need to modify your code a little bit.

```
public static void getTopTenWords(TreeMap<String, ArrayList<Integer>> map) {
    Set<Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>>> set = map.entrySet();

    TreeMap<Integer, String> temp = new TreeMap<Integer, String>();

    for(Map.Entry<String, ArrayList<Integer>> entry : set) {
        int size = entry.getValue().size();
        int word = entry.getKey();

        temp.put(new Integer(size), word));    
    }
}
```

So, you can see that, I just used the `size` of the `values` in your `entry set`. And put it as a `key` in your `TreeMap`. Also using `new Integer(size)` is very important. It ensures that every integer reference points to a new object. Thus no duplication.

Also, note that, your `TreeMap` sorts your `Integer` value in ascending order. Your most frequent words would be somewhere at the end.

Comment: @James.. You're welcome. Do understand the basic things in this answer, that are really important. I would suggest, re-read the answer.